# String.replaceAll(...) of Java not working for \\ and \

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to convert the directory path from:

```
C:\Users\Host\Desktop\picture.jpg
```

to

```
C:\\Users\\Host\\Desktop\\picture.jpg
```

I am using replaceAll() function and other replace functions but they do not work.

How can I do this?

I have printed the statement , it gives me the one which i wanted ie
C:\Users\Host\Desktop\picture.jpg
but now when i pass this variable to open the file, i get this exception why?

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Host\Desktop\picture.jpg

Comment: Please post the exact code you have tried.

Comment: If it's quite urgent, you should probably have spent more time giving more information so that we have a better chance of answering you usefully... please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use :

```
String t2 = t1.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

or (without pattern) :

```
String t2 = t1.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Each "\" has to be preceeded by an other "\". But it's also true for the preceeding "\" so you have to write four backslashes each time you want one in regex.

Comment: Or just use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` - there's no need to use regular expressions here, after all.

Comment: @alain.janinm: Um, really? You're accusing people of providing code which doesn't compile when it does, and you're using an API taking a regular expression when there's no indication that patterns are required. Do you claim your answer is simpler than my use of `replace` instead of `replaceAll`?

Comment: I didnt understand why there are 4 and 8 slashes there, please explain more

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: They're there because `replaceAll` takes a regex pattern - a bad bit of design there. There's no need to use a regex here, so a call to `replace` ends up being simpler.

Comment: Ok so we want "\". In java you have to escape this char because it's a special one. The escape char is "\" too, so setting the second "\" allow you to escape the first "\". Once you have "\\" Java translate that as one regular "\". But you still have to escape this regular one using again 2 backslashes. So you have 4 backslashes for one regular.

Comment: I have edited my problem, Kindly tell me why is this exception coming

Comment: @Natasha: See my edit. Again, you should really read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and think about giving us all the information we might want about what you're trying to do...

Comment: @alain.janinm: Just deleting accusations of posting bad code isn't terribly nice, when it leaves floating comments which then don't make any sense. It would have been better to reply to the comment...

Comment: @JonSkeet I delete my post because you edit your answer, my comment say your code was wrong but now it's correct, I've also remove my -1. So don't be angry you just get all the +1 because I give you the answer... I'm ok with your idea of just using `replace` btw!

Comment: @alain.janinm: Your comment said my code wouldn't even compile before though - when it would. Comments and edits overlap all the time - that's fine - but did you try compiling my code before commenting that it wouldn't compile? Regardless of whether the comment was warranted, it leaves a more sensible comment log if you reply to the later comment rather than deleting your first one. (And no, you didn't "give me the answer" - I'd just temporarily forgotten which way round `replace` and `replaceAll` work.)

Comment: The first thing you post gave me don't compiled, I tried it for real. But sry for the delete post I understand. And for ***I'd just temporarily forgotten which way round replace and replaceAll work.*** <- just lol

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Changed from `replaceAll` to `replace` - you don't need a regex here, so don't use one. (It was a really poor design decision on the part of the Java API team, IMO.)

My *guess* (as you haven't provided enough information) is that you're doing something like:

```
text.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Strings are immutable in Java, so you need to use the return value, e.g.

```
String newText = oldText.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more information.

(I'd also suggest that *usually* you shouldn't be doing this yourself anyway - if this is to include the information in something like a JSON response, I'd expect the wider library to perform escaping for you.)

Note that the doubling is required as `\` is an escape character for Java string (and character) literals. Note that as `replace` doesn't treat the inputs as regular expression patterns, there's no need to perform further doubling, unlike `replaceAll`.

EDIT: You're now getting a `FileNotFoundException` because there *isn't* a filename with double backslashes in - what made you think there was? If you want it as a valid filename, why are you doubling the backslashes?

Comment: String q = str.replaceAll("\","\\");This statement gives me error

Comment: @Natasha of course that will give you an error.  \ is the String escape character in Java; you need to double-escape it, i.e. String q = str.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");

Comment: @Natasha: And yet you don't tell use what the error is. It's also unclear whether you've actually used the code I've given - note the doubling of the backslashes, as the backslash is an escape character in Java string literals.

Comment: what happens when the input string is provided as command line argument

Comment: @alain.janinm: Compiles and executes fine... and doesn't use a regex pointlessly :) (Before my edit, when it was using `replaceAll`, it would have failed at execution time, but it would certainly have compiled. What did you try that *didn't* compile, and what failure did you get?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I mean to say what happens if the string C:\Users\Host\Desktop\picture.jpg is inputted by user as part of command line argument while running the java program. In this case the string will not have \\ in the string right

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: Then it's just a string... it's not clear why you're asking, or what you'd expect...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Oh Sorry, my bad. I tried this on my machine. Everyting is fine. I misunderstood it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In strings \ is bydefault used as escape character therefore in order to select "\" in a string  you have to use "\" and for  "\" (i.e blackslack two times) use "\\". This will solve your problem and thos will also apply to other symbols also like "

Answer (score 0):

Two explanations:

### 1. Replace double backslashes to one (not what you asked)

You have to escape the backslash by backslashes. Like this:

```
String newPath = oldPath.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\");
```

The first parameter needs to be escaped twice. Once for the Java Compiler and once because you use regular expressions. So you want to replace two backslashes by one. So, since we have to escape a backslash add one backslash. Now you have `\\`. This will be compiled to `\`. **BUT!!** you have to escape the backslash once again because the first parameter of the replaceAll method uses regular expressions. So to escape it, add a backslash, but that backslash needs to be escaped, so we get `\\\\`. These for backslashes represents one backslash in the regex. But you want to replace the double backslash to one. So use 8 backslashes.

The second parameter of the replaceAll method isn't using regular expressions, but it has to be escaped as well. So, you need to escape it once for the Java Compiler and once for the replace method: `\\\\`. This is compiled to two backslashes, which are being interpreted as 1 backslash in the replaceAll method.

### 2. Replace single backslash to a pair of backslashes (what you asked)

```
String newPath = oldPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Same logic as above.

### 3. Use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`.

```
String newPath = oldPath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

The difference is that the `replace()` method doesn't use regular expressions, so you don't have to escape every backslash twice for the first parameter.

Hopefully, I explained well...

*-- Edit: Fixed error, as pointed out by xehpuk --*

Comment: @alain.janinm: Jup, you were right. I misread the question. Fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `String newPath = oldPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\");` looks stupid and doesn't work at all. 
It doesn't change the string. `newPath.equals(oldPath)` will always return `true`. And `oldPath.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\")` will throw `IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing`. The reason is that the backslash is a metacharacter in the replacement parameter, too.

Comment: @xehpuk: Nope, I'm sorry. You must have missed something, but this actually does something. First argument is the search target, which is a string, so you have to escape the backslashes by a backslash, in order to make it compile. But then you have a backslash in the string, but the string is interpreted as regex, so you should escape that backslash, because a backslash is something special in a regex. So one backslash in a java string regex is: "\\\\". The second argument is just a string, so only one escape: "\\".

Comment: The second argument is **not** just a string. "Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string" from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much for pointing this out! I learnt something. Thank you :)